# animated photo banner resets instead of repeating the first image css

Tags: html, css

I got this banner thingy from a tutorial, but the thing is, instead of the banner continuing in loops, it resets instead. I don't want to use any javascript since we we're not yet tackling it in uni. Can anyone point out where I did wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

Here are the images:
[[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujquq.png)
[[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXZpf.png)

and this is the code I used

HTML:

```
    <div class="photobanner">
        <img class="first" src="images/scroll/ban.jpg" style="width:350px;height:233px;"/>
        <img src="images/scroll/banner1.png" style="width:350px;height:233px;"/> 
        <img src="images/scroll/banner3.jpg" style="width:350px;height:233px;"/>    
        <img src="images/scroll/banner4.jpg" style="width:350px;height:233px;"/>
        <img src="images/scroll/banner5.jpg" style="width:350px;height:233px;"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*body and container*/
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

body {
background-image:url(images/banner1takuya.jpg);     
background-size: cover;     
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#container {
width:865px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
padding:0 0 30px 0;
background-image:url(images/bg.png); 
}

/*header*/
header {
width: 800px;
margin: 40px auto;
}

header h1 {
text-align: center;
font: 100 60px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header p {
font: 100 15px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
text-align: justify;
}

/*photobanner*/

.photobanner {
height: 233px;
width: 3550px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.photobanner img {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
cursor: pointer;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}


/*keyframe animations*/
.first {
-webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "bannermove" {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
margin-left: -2125px;
}

}

@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
margin-left: -2125px;
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
margin-left: -2125px;
}

}

@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
margin-left: -2125px;
}

}

@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
margin-left: -2125px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the .photobanner width set to 3550px, but the sum of images' widths is 355*5=1775px only.

You need to add 5 more images of the same size and this will work correctly.